# Stripping headers and footers

Tags: python, ruby

What would be the most elegant way to do this (which I do in Ruby) in python.

```
private_key = base64data.to_s.sub('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
private_key = private_key.sub('-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
```

Basically I need to strip the header and footers of the private key string.

Regards.

Comment: base64data.to_s.delete('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----') is probably the proper way in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward:

```
private_key = private_key.replace('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
private_key = private_key.replace('-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
```

Comment: Nice - Even more elegant than Ruby. Getting to love Python! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python [`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is equivalent to `sub` in Ruby:

```
private_key = base64data.replace('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
private_key = private_key.replace('-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '')
```

Or using regular expressions:

```
import re
private_key = re.sub(r'-----(BEGIN|END) RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '', base64data)
```

Comment: Or - can think of it from the other way around, and get the text between... `re.search('BEGIN(.*?)END', base64data).group(1)` but with the outer bits spelt out fully ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [pyasn1 documentation](http://snmplabs.com/pyasn1/example-use-case.html) has a nice one liner for this. The key file is opened, the first and last lines are stripped during the read process, and then everything else is joined back together.

```
with open('.ssh/id_rsa') as key_file:
    b64_serialisation = ''.join(key_file.readlines()[1:-1])
```